# Join as a bifunctor

Tags: simplicial-stuff, infinity-categories, infinity-topos-theory

I have been reading these great [notes](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Erezk/quasicats.pdf) by Charles Rezk, and one thing that has been bothering me is the join construction. To solve lifting problems in quasicategory theory we use the Leibniz construction, namely given a bifunctor $F: A \times B \to C$ that is bidivisible, namely sits in a two-variable adjunction $F \dashv \{ G, H \}$:
$$ C(F(a,b), c) \cong B(b, G(a,c)) \cong A(a, H(b,c))$$
there is an induced two-variable adjunction in the arrow categories $F' \dashv \{ G', H' \}$ with $F': A^I \times B^I \to C^I$. See Emily Riehl's Categorical Homotopy Theory Construction 11.1.7.

When $F: C \times C \to C$ has a two-variable adjunction such that $G \cong H$, we say it is closed. In $\mathsf{sSet}$ the bifunctor $- \times - : \mathsf{sSet} \times \mathsf{sSet} \to \mathsf{sSet}$ is bidivisible and closed, and the induced two-variable adjunction is the pushout product and pullback hom, which is used extensively to prove major theorems in quasicategory theory.

One can prove that the join construction $- * -: \mathsf{sSet} \times \mathsf{sSet} \to \mathsf{sSet}$ is not bidivisible, because it doesn't preserve the initial object in each component. However, we can consider the functors $- * X, X * -: \mathsf{sSet} \to \mathsf{sSet}_{X/}$. In this case they do have right adjoints, but they can't coalesce into a unique bifunctor since the codomain is changing for each $X$. In Rezk's notes, and in all other references that I could find, one still gets a more complicated induced adjunction and a resulting pushout join product and pullback slice hom, but we cannot prove their usual properties by the techniques developed for a bidivisible closed bifunctor, we have to do everything by hand.

Now there is an alternative construction where one takes $- *' -: \mathsf{sSet} \times \mathsf{sSet} \to \mathsf{sSet}$ by giving the simplicial sets the augmentation $X_{-1} = \pi_0(X)$, and setting $(X * Y)_n = \coprod_{i = -1}^n X_i \times Y_{n - 1 - i}$. This bifunctor is bidivisible, and when $X$ and $Y$ are connected, $X * Y = X *' Y$. So my question is: What are the objectwise adjoints to $- *' -$? Can we use these to model the slice categories  and develop the theory of (co)limits in quasicategories?

Comment: The cleanest way to develop the basic properties of join and slice of simplicial sets is to see them as operations on augmented simplicial sets. This is the approach taken in Joyal’s original paper on ‘Quasi-categories and Kan complexes’.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of this is explained elegantly in Appendix D.2 in Riehl & Verity's Elements of $\infty$-category theory, and actually answers all of my questions. As Alexander Campbell says, the real important concept is the join as a bifunctor of augmented simplicial sets. Taking $\pi_0$ or the trivial augmentation is not as important. We can use the functor category two-variable adjunction on augmented simplicial sets and then just forget the augmentations.